# how to reset jquery ui slider on element click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to reset jquery UI slider for different elements click using only one slider

when I click on each element I want to reset this slider

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.
Please do not just post an image.

Comment: hey thanks but I don't understand check below one how he explains me bay the way thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to create one function like below and you will have to call on click

```
    slider_reset(); 

    var slider_reset = function(){
        var $slider = jQuery("#slider-id");
        $slider.slider("option", 'value', 20);
        $('#amount').val('20')
        $slider.slider("option", 'max', 500);
    }
```